# Drupal 7 Custom Module | Create a button in settings page that calls a custom function

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've created a custom module with it's own settings page where the administrator can set certain parameters (radio buttons, input fields and dropdown).

I'm looking for a way to create a button in the form that will perform a custom function.
(Example: Like the 'clear all caches' button in the admin page.)

What's the easiest or best way to create this?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each different button on your form can perform a different function by assigning it the [`#submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) property:

```
function mymodule_my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['button1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Perform 1st Action',
    '#submit' => array('mymodule_my_form_action_one')
  );

  $form['button2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Perform 2nd Action',
    '#submit' => array('mymodule_my_form_action_two')
  );
}

function mymodule_my_form_action_one($form, &$form_state) {
  // Perform the 1st action
}


function mymodule_my_form_action_two($form, &$form_state) {
  // Perform the 2nd action
}
```

Only the specified submit function will run for each button click.